# c# SavePath format explanation

Tags: asp.net

I have been looking at save paths and have noticed the following being used interchangeably. Could anyone help me understand the differences between each syntax and the consequences. If any of them seem incorrect, please tell me why and what is the correct format.

A verbatim string uses the prefix character "@":

```
string savePath = @"\\EMT\D\test_folder\\test.docx";

string savePath = @"\\EMT\D\\test_folder\\test.docx";

string savePath = @"\\EMT\D\test_folder\test.docx";

string savePath = "\\\\EMT\\D\\\\test_folder\\test.tif";

string savePath = "c:\\test_folder\\test.pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character has to be escaped in a normal string. You escape it by doing a double backslash.

However, this is not necessary if you use the @ sign, which changes it from a normal string to a string literal. You'll often see Windows paths displayed in code as a string literal since windows uses the backslash character as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `verbatim string` use this syntax and don't use backslash `\` twice

```
string savePath = @"c:\test_folder\test.pdf";
```

If you want to use escape backslashes then use this:

```
string savePath = "c:\\test_folder\\test.pdf";
```

But don't do both in the same time.

Comment: What if the path is a relative network path:-
string savePath = @"\\EMT\D\test_folder\\test.docx";